# How to form a dictionary for use in JSON body from a Pandas data frame?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have the starting data frame looking like this:

```
my_list = [
    ['Japan', 'Flowers'],
    ['United States', 'Guns', 'yes'],
    ['Japan', 'Sushi'],
    ['South Korea', 'Sunscreen']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(my_list, columns=["country", "sector", "flag"])
```

[image]

I need the output to be in this exact format of a dictionary for an API request, but I can't format it exactly as it needs to be using to_dict() method. The "id" is the number of row from the data frame where the data is located.

```
{"groups":
[
    {
        "name": "Japan",
        "groups":
            [
                {"name": "Flowers", "ids": [0]}
            ],
        "groups":
            [
                {"name": "Sushi", "ids": [2]}
            ]
    },
    {
        "name": "United States",
        "groups":
            [
                {
                    "name": "Guns",
                    "groups":
                        [
                            {"name": "yes", "ids": [1]}
                        ]
                }
            ]
    },
    {
        "name": "South Korea",
        "groups":
            [
                {"name": "Sunscreen",
                 "ids": [3]}
            ]
    }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
out = []
for idx, g in df.groupby("country"):
    out.append({"name": idx})
    ids = {}
    for i, s in g["sector"].iteritems():
        ids.setdefault(s, []).append(i)
    out[-1]["groups"] = [{"name": k, "ids": v} for k, v in ids.items()]


out = {"groups": out}
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "groups": [
        {
            "name": "Japan",
            "groups": [
                {"name": "Flowers", "ids": [0]},
                {"name": "Sushi", "ids": [2]},
            ],
        },
        {"name": "South Korea", "groups": [{"name": "Sunscreen", "ids": [3]}]},
        {"name": "United States", "groups": [{"name": "Guns", "ids": [1]}]},
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Andrej, yes this is very helpful but now I realized that the desired output has several keys named groups which cannot be achieved in a python dict. Any idea if I can write this somehow to a json file so it is the same as required?

Comment: @Janet I'd recommend to open a new question here on StackOverflow. Put there code you have, sample input and expected output. I'll try to look at it.